# Como tirar o autocomplete automático do autofilename?

Tags: sublime-text

Gostaria de saber como retirar o *autocomplete* automático do *autofilename*, sempre que abro as aspas ele mostra os diretórios e isso esta chateando.

Alguém sabe como não deixar ele automático e usar tipo o comando <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> pra ele mostrar o diretório igual no Netbeans?

Comment: Qual versão do sublime?

Comment: Boa pergunta. Isso me irrita em todo editor que já usei até hoje...

Comment: A Versão é Sublime text 3.